# powershell script to create folders named by date and a .1, .2, .3 etc at the end of it, it will be running via task scheduler

Tags: powershell

Looking for suggestions on how to solve a little issue, I have powershell script I am working on, it is going to be run say 5 times a day, and will create a folder that is todays days and then like a .1 at the end of it, I will then copy files to that 1 specific folder, then the next time the script runs the folder will be .2 then copy files to that folder, but the problem that I am running into doing as if/elseif statements is the 2nd time it runs it says the .1 file already exists and stops running.

any thoughts on how to get around this?

here is my current set up

```
if ($Folder1 -eq ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).1") {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).1"
    $Folder1 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).1"
} 
elseif ($Folder1 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).1"){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).2"
    $Folder2 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).2"
}
elseif ($Folder2 -eq ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).2"){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).3"
    $Folder3 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).3"
}
elseif ($Folder3 -eq ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).3"){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).4"
    $Folder4 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).4"
}
elseif ($Folder4 -eq ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).4"){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).5"
    $Folder5 = ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).5"
}

else {

    "Path doesn't exist."
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Would you be able to provide the context of how you're deriving `$Folder1` intitially?

Comment: basically just creating a variable with the path in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An-dir's answer is great, and I'm just going to offer a slightly more compact version because some people like that kind of thing.

```
$NewFolder=$Folder="C:\Temp\"+(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
While(Test-Path ($NewFolder="$Folder."+ ++$i)){}
$NewFolder = New-Item -Type Directory -Path $NewFolder
```

Like I said, same thing just a little more compact. Also shows a couple things I wasn't aware of for a long time with PowerShell, so I thought others might learn things like:

```
$This = $That = "Some Value"
```

Setting two variables in the same line to the same thing.

```
While(Test-Path ($NewFolder="$Folder."+ ++$i))
```

Assigning a value to a variable, and being able to test against that value at the same time. Works with `If`, `Where`, and all those kinds of things that allow you to perform an evaluation that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might be what you need if I was able to understand your needs. I do validate if the folder for the current date with appended ".n" exists. The "n" is the current folder version starting with 1.

```
$folder = "c:\temp\"
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
do {
    $i++
    $NewFolder = Join-Path $folder ($today+".$i")
} while (Test-Path $NewFolder)
New-Item -Type Directory -Path $NewFolder | Out-Null
```